# SSRS Multiple IF SUM based on paramter

Tags: if-statement, reporting-services, parameters, sum

I've been struggling with this for a few hours if anyone can help.

=IIF(Parameters!Agent.Value ="Susan Calladine", (Sum(Fields!Susan_Calladine.Value) / Sum(Fields!InvitedToApply.Value), 
IIF(Parameters!Agent.Value ="Fazaila Pirbhai", (Sum(Fields!Fazaila_Pirbhai.Value) / Sum(Fields!InvitedToApply.Value), 
IIF(Parameters!Agent.Value ="Claire Willis", (Sum(Fields!Claire_Willis.Value) / Sum(Fields!InvitedToApply.Value),0)))

Basically to calculate specific fields based on the value of the parameter being returend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the error you're getting no doubt refers to a ')' being expected either add a closing ) to each of your SUM clauses

`(Sum(Fields!Susan_Calladine.Value) / Sum(Fields!InvitedToApply.Value))`

or get rid of the opening ( in each case

`Sum(Fields!Susan_Calladine.Value) / Sum(Fields!InvitedToApply.Value)`.

Personally I'd go for the second as it will make the expression a little more readable